# Overriding Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction() in Magento

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, overloading

I am having trouble overriding one of Magento's core controllers, the WishList Index Controller. When I add a product in the wishlist, I need Magento to redirect back to the product page instead of the wishlist. Here is what I did so far

1. Created a folder in app/code/local, called MyCompany, with a subfolder called Coreextensions.
2. Inside the Coreextensions folder, I created etc/config.xml, with the following content:

No, this instance is intended for use outside of production or under the RDS Free Usage Tier

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Coreextensions>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_Coreextensions>
    </modules>
 
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyCompany_Coreextensions before="Mage_Wishlist">
                            MyCompany_Coreextensions_Wishlist
                        </MyCompany_Coreextensions>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

3. Inside Coreextensions folder, I created controllers/Wishlist/IndexController.php, like this:

```
  <?php
    /* Stay on product page after adding to wishlist */
  require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Wishlist').DS.'IndexController.php');
    
    class MyCompany_Coreextensions_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController
    {
      
    /**
     * Add the item to wish list
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action|void
     */
    protected function _addItemToWishList()
    {
        $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            return $this->norouteAction();
        }
    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    
        $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        if (!$productId) {
            $this->_redirect('*/');
            return;
        }
    
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
            $session->addError($this->__('Cannot specify product.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/');
            return;
        }
    
        try {
            $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            if ($session->getBeforeWishlistRequest()) {
                $requestParams = $session->getBeforeWishlistRequest();
                $session->unsBeforeWishlistRequest();
            }
            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($requestParams);
    
            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($result)) {
                Mage::throwException($result);
            }
            $wishlist->save();
    
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'wishlist_add_product',
                array(
                    'wishlist' => $wishlist,
                    'product' => $product,
                    'item' => $result
                )
            );
    
            $referer = $session->getBeforeWishlistUrl();
            if ($referer) {
                $session->setBeforeWishlistUrl(null);
            } else {
                $referer = $this->_getRefererUrl();
            }
    
            /**
             *  Set referer to avoid referring to the compare popup window
             */
            $session->setAddActionReferer($referer);
    
            Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();
    
            $message = $this->__('%1$s has been added to your wishlist. Click <a href="%2$s">here</a> to continue shopping.',
                $product->getName(), Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($referer));
            $session->addSuccess($message);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.'));
        }
    
        //$this->_redirect('*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
    
    }
```

3. In app/etc/modules, I created MyCompany_Coreextensions.xml, like this:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--we need to enable this module as any other if-->
    <!--you wish to do it as standalone module extension-->
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MyCompany_Coreextensions>
                <active>true</active>
                <codepool>local</codepool>
            </MyCompany_Coreextensions>
        </modules>
    </config>
   ```

Of course, this doesn't work and it's driving me nuts. If I make the change in the Core file, it works as I want it to, but I wouldn't want to alter the Core files... Let me say that YES, I did clear the cache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are right but only two things:

1. you have to add this row `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php';` first of Controller class declaration;
2. the name of your Controller class must be without '*_Wishlist*' so `MyCompany_Coreextensions_IndexController` instead of `MyCompany_Coreextensions_Wishlist_IndexController` (you have to change it into config.xml too -> `<MyCompany_Coreextensions before="Mage_Wishlist">MyCompany_Coreextensions</MyCompany_Coreextensions>` instead of `<MyCompany_Coreextensions before="Mage_Wishlist">MyCompany_Coreextensions_Wishlist</MyCompany_Coreextensions>`)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Magento EE, you should replace:

```
<MyCompany_Coreextensions before="Mage_Wishlist">
```

with:

```
<MyCompany_Coreextensions before="Enterprise_Wishlist">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you haven't "included" or "required" the original(core) IndexController of wishlist, you have to do in your module's index controller file like below:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
```

The above code should be placed before any class declaration in your module's IndexController.php file.

Also you have spaces between "<" and tag names, so do remove them or xml structure will break, showing fatal errors in magento.

Once you do that refresh magento caches and then try adding product to wishlist, you will be redirected to previous url.

Answer (score -1):

```
< codepool >local< /codepool >
```

You have to change `codepool` to `codePool` if you still not figure it out